# (wx python) auto size a text in a boxsizer

Tags: python, text, wxpython, wxwidgets, boxsizer

I'm using wxpython for an app however I can't auto size a text using wx.statictext (is there a way to display text without using that ?) and this text is in a boxsizer but when I resize my window it doesn't work contrary to my buttons...

(I already search and try things using size or wrap...)

Thanks for all

EDIT: here's some code to illustrate, resize the window and you'll see that the text doesn't resize itself

```
import wx
import wx.grid as grid
import time

date=time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y ? %H:%M')

app = wx.App()
win = wx.Frame(None, title="Title", size=(410, 335))
bkg = wx.Panel(win)

loadButton = wx.Button(bkg, label='Open',size=(200,40))
saveButton = wx.Button(bkg, label='Save',size=(200,40))
QRbutton=wx.Button(bkg, label='qr',size=(200,40))

ddate=wx.StaticText(bkg,-1,date)

bkg.grid = grid.Grid(bkg)
bkg.grid.CreateGrid(20, 5)

chronobox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
chronobox.Add(saveButton, proportion=2, flag=wx.SHAPED|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, border=5)
chronobox.Add(loadButton, proportion=2, flag=wx.SHAPED|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, border=5)

hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
hbox.Add(ddate, proportion=5,flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
hbox.Add(chronobox, proportion=2, flag=wx.EXPAND| wx.ALL, border=5)
hbox.Add(QRbutton, proportion=1, flag=wx.SHAPED|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, border=5)

globalbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
globalbox.Add(hbox, proportion=5, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)
globalbox.Add(bkg.grid, proportion=4,flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT | wx.BOTTOM | wx.RIGHT, border=5)

bkg.SetSizer(globalbox)
win.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking? What do the buttons do that the text does not? Some example code demonstrating your problem would help a lot.

Comment: Are you expecting the static text to be vertically central in that area, or the font size to scale up to fit in that area?

Comment: I know how to set the static text on an area (I mean top right, bottom left etc) but I don't know how to scale up  the front size to fit in the boxsizer when the window is resize so have you got an idea how I can doing that ? except using the resize window event ?

Comment: It is scaling the same (notice the buttons font size isn't changing either), just you can't see the background on the statictext like you can on a button. Try adding `ddate.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)` and you should then be able to see that it does scale within the sizer when the window resizes.

Comment: Ahhhhh I understand, so how can I change the size of the static text when the window is resize ?

Comment: I've never tried before, I'll try and see if I can put something together tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

The description of SetLabel function is Sets the static text label and updates the controls size to exactly fit the label unless the control has wxST_NO_AUTORESIZE flag.
If you want to change the font size, you could reference this [article](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/04/28/wxpython-learning-to-use-fonts/).